# array_count_values i want to echo one specific key value

Tags: php, wordpress, loops, woocommerce, vendor

Im busy with a webshop and i want to echo how many orders this day has needs to delivert

I have a loop where i got the following code in:

```
$winkels[] = $vendor->id;
```

Thats good i got as i did the following code:

```
echo '<pre>'.print_r(array_count_values($winkels),true).'</pre>';
```

Than i get as result:

```
Array
(
   [63] => 1
   [45] => 1
   [85] => 1
   [59] => 1
)
```

The results are good, but how can i echo the value of id: 63 ?

Please can somebody help me out?

Comment: `$data = array_count_values($winkels);  echo $data[63];`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For single one:-

```
$data = array_count_values($winkels); 
echo $data[63];
```

For all:-

```
$data = array_count_values($winkels); 
foreach($data as $key=>$val){
  echo $key.'=>'.$val;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For 63 you can `array_count_values($winkels)[63]` similar for another keys.